# Download file from Azure Blob Storage client side

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want download file from azure blob storage like download file from google drive (click download and progress show on bottom of browser, i dont know how we call that?). Some example on the internet show way download to folder directly it will not working when i publish my backend to the server, it will find the directory from the server not clientside (of course it will not working).
So, how can i do that? use http request?
It so great if we have example for this solution. Sorry im new here.

Thanks a lot guys,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about downloading to the dir that you assign using Python.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

filename = "test.txt"
container_name="test-container"
path="D:\\demo\\download\\" #the dir that you download to

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("{Connection string}")
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(filename)

with open(path + filename, "wb") as f:
    data = blob_client.download_blob()
    data.readinto(f)
```

`path + filename` is the file that is downloaded to the local address.